# Why do I need to call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to allow a visual to properly bind before printing?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, printing, dispatcher

I have a UserControl with a fixed size of 850x1100 to give me the same aspect ratio as a letter-sized piece of paper. I display this in my window inside a `Viewbox`, and it acts much like a print preview. The control inherits my window's DataContext, and when it's displayed on the screen, all the bindings work and it looks wonderful.

I've written the code below in my window's code behind (I feel it's a totally view-oriented operation) to attempt to print it. If I execute this code as written, the control prints, but does not appear to be data bound.

```
private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var dlg = new PrintDialog();
    var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (result == null || !(bool)result)
        return;

    var page = new InspectionFormPrintView { DataContext = this.DataContext };

    page.Measure(new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, dlg.PrintableAreaHeight));
    page.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), page.DesiredSize));

    dlg.PrintVisual(page, "Inspection Form");
}
```

If I modify the last line in that method to

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => dlg.PrintVisual(page, "Inspection Form")), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, null);
```

it will print just fine. Why is this?

Comment: I would guess all [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) with `Loaded` (enumeration value 6) or below will work. I think with the default `DispatcherPriority.Normal` page layout isn't ready yet.

Comment: You could also try to force page.UpdateLayout() instead of the page.Measure and page.Arrange. (can't test it, but had a similar issue once).
Your original PrintVisual call is not working properly because the UI hasn't updated yet (WPF works asynchronously). By using the Invoke your call is queued and executed after the UI is updated (when the app is idle again), that's why it is working..

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't appear to be databound"?

Comment: When the control prints, places where there should be data (like in a TextBlock) have none, and items who's visibility is bound to a bool property using a BooleanToVisibilityConverter do not collapse when the property is false, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by LPL in the comments, this is required because WPF needs to perform the all the data bindings. Since WPF operations are queued on the `Dispatcher`, you need to queue your print operation to complete after `DispatcherPriority.DataBind`. Therefore, calling `BeginInvoke` with `DispatcherPriority.Render` or lower will give WPF time to process the bindings on the control, so they show up in your printed output.